# Hangouts Chat Bot: Use Google Apps Script, but execute as me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I am creating a [GAS Hangouts Chat bot](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot) for use within my G Suite domain. I have opted for the [Apps Script architecture](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/structure), as I want to use Google Sheets as a data store.

Since I use Google Sheets in the script, the bot prompts every new user to authorize it to use Google Sheets. [If you publish a Google Apps Script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions), you have the option to say "Execute the app as me" instead of "Execute the app as user accessing the web app". Can I do this with my chat bot?

I want the bot to come pre-authorized to write to my google sheet (because it's executing as me) without asking new users for authorization.